# Reclassify raster value

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder, reclassify

I'm curious if anyone has been able to change one individual value in a raster file?  I'm using Arc 10.2 and trying to change the value 99 to -2 for 144 files using model builder.  So far, I've only been successful using reclassify tool that requires me to manually eliminate the remaining value points.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could try Con in raster calculator: Con((Raster == 99),-2,Raster). You need spatial analyst license to do this http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000005000000. Otherwise look at GDAL_Calc http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html

Comment: I think the GDAL_Calc syntax is *gdal_calc.py -A input.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A*(A!=99)" --calc="-2*(A==99)" * but I've not had need to try this utility yet (I've only recently heard of it) and am not familiar with the syntax (yet)

Comment: The Con tool is indeed the way to go. For gdal_calc, I would say --calc="A*(A!=99)-2*(A==99)"